# Grab Data on the Fly from Table HTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This might be a little difficult to explain, but I am displaying a grid that is 2 x 2. When you click on the text of a cell (say 0,1) it will bring up a pop-up box and store those coordinates in hidden values. Those hidden values will be then submitted to a form via POST.

Here is some sample code I have written to hopefully clarify what I am trying to do: https://jsfiddle.net/v08bzm9k/1/

```
<table border=1>
<tr>
  <td class='grid-cells'><a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup'>1</a></td>
  <td class='grid-cells'><a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup'>2</a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class='grid-cells'><a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup'>3</a></td>
  <td class='grid-cells'><a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup'>4</a></td>
</tr>
</table>

<div data-role="popup" id="myPopup" class="ui-content" style="min-width:250px;">
      <form method="post" action="save-square.php">
        <div>
          <h3>Pick This Square:</h3>
          <label for="name" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name">
          <label for="email" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Email:</label>
          <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="submit" data-inline="true" value="Submit">
          <div id='row'></div>
          <div id='col'></div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
```

Would I store the values of the cell I click into hidden fields via JavaScript?

Comment: sounds reasonable if that is what you need at back end to keep track with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated https://jsfiddle.net/v08bzm9k/2/

Yes you can use hidden fields. In your form add this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="coords" id="coords" value="">
```

Add this JS to your page:

```
function setCoords(newCoords) {
    $('#coords').val(newCoords);
}
```

And in your links, add an onClick:

```
<a href='#myPopup' data-rel='popup' onclick="setCoords('1,1');">1</a>
```

Comment: I have tried to make these adjustments, but it does not set the `hidden` values to the `newCoords`. I put a `alert` in the JS to make sure it was running and it was, but it doesn't actually change the `hidden` input's values correctly.

Comment: If you are looking at the value attribute in source, it will show whatever value was set when the page loaded (nothing, probably). However, if you post the form you should find that your save-square.php script receives the coordinates in `$_POST['coords']`. Alternatively, in the console you can do something like `jQuery('[name=coords]').val()` to see that they have been updated

Comment: Actually - looking closer the input needs an id too - change the input in your form to `<input type="hidden" name="coords" value="" id="coords">` - then the setCoords function will access it and update the values correctly

Comment: Oh, right. I put it in the fiddle but forgot it above. Fixed. Also worth mentioning if you make the input TEXT instead of HIDDEN you can see the value change clearly.